# Picturebox equivalent with image?

Tags: c#, xaml

Where I found in toolbox, "picturebox"? I found in my toolbox, "image". Is the same with picturebox?

Answer (score 0):

You should use **Picturebox** to draw something, display Bitmap images and etc.

**Image** control allow you to show pictures in application. you should use this control only for displaying images(like user avatar, programm logo...)